# Add order by clause to delete in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I want to delete a table in descending order. My query has joins as well. As jooq does not support order by with delete, are there any workarounds?

Comment: why?   ... order by in delete in unsuseful  .. could be you are looking for a select with order by

Comment: @scaisEdge, maybe there are on-delete triggers? Does that even work?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have foreign key constraints within the same table so i need to delete rows in a certain order

Comment: then you must select in the order you need  and delete one by one  ..  wiith  loop over the select result ... delete have not an order by clause

Comment: @scaisEdge This process will be very heavy as my table is huge

Answer (score 0):

As per [MySQL docs, chapter 13.2.2 DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) you can't use `ORDER BY` with a `DELETE` statement that spans more than one table:

> **Multi-Table Deletes**
>
> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows from one or more tables depending on the condition in the WHERE clause. You cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a multiple-table DELETE.

If JOOQ doesn't `ORDER BY` on `DELETE` I'm afraid you have to write plain SQL and JDBC.

Comment: I'm deleting from one target table. Although for the condition in where clause i'm using joins

Comment: Support for multi-table deletes will be implemented in the near future.
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/delete-statement/